# I cannot update InputField using Formik for conditionally rendered Component and nested initialState

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have in my app conditionally rendered component where I have few InputText and to update it I'm using Formik library. This conditionally rendered component called  shares the same initialState as main component, but it's biuld as nested initialState.
Here You can see few InputText from

```
const AdditionalPersonComponent = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Additional Person</h4>
        <StyledInputRow>
          <FloatingLabel text="Person name" name="Person name">
            <StyledInputText
              id="personName"
              name="personName"
              value={values.person.personName}
              onChange={handleChange}
              type="text"
            />
          </FloatingLabel>
          <FloatingLabel text="Last Name" name="Last Name">
            <StyledInputText
              id="personLastName"
              name="personLastName"
              value={values.person.personLastName}
              onChange={handleChange}
              type="text"
            />
          </FloatingLabel>
```

And here how all initialState looks, state from conditionally rendered is the one from property person:{}

```
const { values, handleChange, handleSubmit } = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      name: currentEmployee.name,
      lastName: currentEmployee.lastName,
      cooperationForm: currentEmployee.cooperationForm,
      package: luxmeds.luxmedType.package,
      type: luxmeds.luxmedType.type,
      totalCost: luxmeds.luxmedType.cost,
      employerCost: luxmeds.luxmedType.package || 0,
      employeeCost: luxmeds.luxmedType.package || 0,
      comments: luxmeds.luxmedType.package || 0,
      person: {
        personName: luxmeds.person.name,
        personLastName: luxmeds.person.lastName,
        personCooperationForm: '',
        personPackage: '',
        personType: luxmeds.person.type,
        personTotalCost: '',
        personEmployerCost: luxmeds.luxmedType.cost,
        personEmployeeCost: '',
        personComments: '',
      },
    },
```

Can You please suggest how to build it to make it work ?

regards

Comment: I haven't used Formik in a while, but doesn't it expect the name to be the property path of the field you want to update? For example should `name="personName"` not be `name="person.personName"`?

Comment: You mean in conditionally rendered component ? Sorry I didn't get Your suggestion, I mean looks like You suggest something which I have implemented, or ?